# PHP $_GET with value = "http://abc.com" results in permission denied

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [403 Forbidden Error While Sending GET Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951011/403-forbidden-error-while-sending-get-data)

When a $_GET variable contains the value "http://abc.com", the page returns "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /get.php on this server."

You can try it out at http://softwareholic.com/get.php (output with var_dump($_GET);)

These are ok

```
softwareholic.com/get.php?link=123 //output: array(1) { ["link"]=> string(3) "123" } 
softwareholic.com/get.php?link=http:// //output: array(1) { ["link"]=> string(7) "http://" }
```

These will fail

```
softwareholic.com/get.php?link=http://google.com  
softwareholic.com/get.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

The thing is they worked on my localhost and downtownhost.com. The problem shows up only on hostgator.com. I have also remove .htaccess to narrow things down.

Any ideas?

Comment: This fails - `http://softwareholic.com/get.php?link=http://abc.` Can you check your `.htaccess` if there are any directives which match/fail this filter.

Comment: @Pushpesh — The question states that the .htaccess was removed.

Comment: Oh! sorry, didn't see that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host is enforcing the `403` as a security measure, probably in an attempt to prevent [Open Redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) vulnerabilities.

Do you really need to redirect to any given URL by the user? How about storing possible URLs in a database table, and passing in the ID in the querystring, then lookup and redirect.

Comment: I'm using it as a bookmarklet to pass the location.href link to my server. I thought it would be straightforward. Will strip the http:// and add it back on the server side. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, when stripping the http:// keep in mind you might get some https:// so need to handle that in your code.