# laravel socialite showing HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden for google login

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-plus, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

Laravel socialite showing HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden for google login on the callback but working fine for facebook login. Previously it was working fine but after adding SSL it is showing the error I am not able to find out what is the problem, same code was running fine on another subdomain, Google plus API is enabled. Someone, please help me out
here is the URL - [www.beingreligious.com](https://www.beingreligious.com)

When i login with google with it return

```
https://www.beingreligious.com/auth/google/callback?state=JSqZHyIkS6bLMTMHZ4dMmbgXJwbXuDiwOqVBSp7I&code=4/WgDWcviWNpyVBB4ScPG7mNzQAveXOAlc9dQ5bvwn7BVhfUyCBegloMU7lK3O7hGxSphyHp86Nm36Vl40eE3LsNc&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=1&session_state=db2d5443920526f58d68ac724e14f4e5af70497f..2a92&prompt=consent#
```

here is the callback function

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request,$provider)
    {
        //echo "here"; die;
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider,$request);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        $next=session()->get('nextbtn');
        if($next!='')
        {
        return redirect('/check_sign_up?next='.$next);
        }else{
        return redirect('/check_sign_up');
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we cant help debuging what we cant see

Comment: hey @DaImTo thanx for your reply . i added the callback function code in my question please have a look

Comment: have you update the url on google app ?

Comment: @bhaskar i added the url on google app and also on .env file

Comment: ok let me check. Please set APP_DEBUG = true; on server. And let me know

Comment: APP_DEBUG is already true . can your visit this link https://www.beingreligious.com/login and login with google . than you will understand what the problem is. on the same url if you login with facebook it is working

Comment: Please add code you wrote in Route file for route : `/auth/google/callback` and Controller function

Comment: Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'HomeController@handleProviderCallback'); it's the code of route

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Hey @DaImTo i added the screenshot of error page in the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18272557/1841839

Comment: hey @DaImTo problem is not with website its only with the google login. if you open the website link you'll see the website is running fine

Comment: @ManojNegi the issue is seems because of route. Unable to find route defination in web.php.

Comment: actually the issue is with the data returning by the google. and i have no idea how to resolve it

Comment: Then confirm this by uncomment `//echo "here"; die;`. Check if it prints here in page then let me know.

Comment: yes its printing "here" when i access the url without returning parameters

Comment: No everything keep the same. Just uncomment that line. And try to login with google. and check

Comment: hey if i remove "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" from the callback url than its working

Comment: Ok then go to the Google app and enable this library access.

Comment: its already enabled

Comment: @ManojNegi Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue because of Mod-security rule set up on my domain. ModSecurity is one of the apache server modules that provides a complete website protection by defending hackers and other malicious attacks.

I requested my server provider to disable it for my domain, because I am using a shared server. After it, I didn't face this issue and the google login is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Still, issue continuing,

click this link, you will get 403 error.
https://www.beingreligious.com/?scope=http%3A%2F%2F

Reference here

[403 Forbidden Error While Sending GET Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951011/403-forbidden-error-while-sending-get-data)